# Get data from Database when entering Barcode in to a Table field in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tablecolumn

[Items Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDSHW.png)

hi,
I'm doing a POS and Inventory project using JavaFX. The situation is, I need to get the corresponding item details from the database when I scan an item Barcode into the Barcode column, into the same row, as shown in the picture but don't know how to do. I tried the following code but don't know how to move further:

BarcodeColumn.setEditable(true);

```
    BarcodeColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Items,String>("Barcode"));
    BarcodeColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    BarcodeColumn.setOnEditCommit(

    new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Items, String>>() {
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Items, String> t) {

            ((Items) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setBarcode(t.getNewValue());

        }


    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO - and please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ;)

Comment: I personally would not let the BC scanner populate the BC field in the `TableView`. I would retrieve all the `TableView'`s data based on the BC number. Then I would use all the data from the query to populate the `TableView`.